# 'unexpected error' while training Object Detection model - CreateML

Tags: swift, macos, machine-learning, createml, createmlui

I've been attempting to train an object detection model through CreateML to incorporate into my iOS application, however I am running into an issue that occurs somewhere near the 300th iteration of the training.   I receive a pop-up saying "Unable to resume this training", "Discard current progress or duplicate this model source to restart training" along with the error message: "Unexpected error" in the left hand corner of the window.  Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBWAj.jpg).

Does anyone know what could possibly be causing the error and or how to fix it?  I appreciate the help!

Cheers,

Keil

Comment: Any luck with this? I am getting the same :(

Comment: I think this means there is no more space on disk available but it's annoying how it leaves behind tons of iterations when you get this message